# MVC and Ajax injected Models in Razor view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

My MVC 5 application accepts surveys from it's users.  I inherited the EF models which are laid out roughly like this:

Survey

- Questions

  - Answers

I have been asked to make the survey dynamic by adding a NestedSurveyId to the Answer object.  when that answer is selected a new Survey model is displayed underneath by calling a partial view by passing the NestedSurveyId to the controller.

That part all works (the display).  The problem is that I can't figure out how to extract the newly added model from the page when it is sent to the controller.

I don't know whether doing it this way is a good idea or not. The reason (perhaps a bad one) for not adding nested Survey models like this...

Survey

- Questions

  - Answers

    - Survey

....is that we sometimes have 20 questions and I'm afraid the query will kill the database.

These surveys are answered when a customer signs up on our site and the post goes to a controller with this signature

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCompany(AddCompanyModel model)
```

The injected survey is obtained by calling this

```
public ActionResult ShowNestedSurvey(int surveyId)
```

This is the ajax

```
@section scripts
```

{

```
    $(":radio").click(function() {

        var questionId = this.getAttribute("data-questionId");
        var nestedSurveyId = this.getAttribute("data-nestedSurveyId");
        if (nestedSurveyId != null && nestedSurveyId > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Register/jenc/company/ShowNestedSurvey",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: "answerId=" + nestedSurveyId,
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#' + questionId).html(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#' + questionId).html("There was an error getting the survey question.");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#' + questionId).html("");
        }

    });

    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        alert('submitting');
        return;
    });
</script>
```

}

I'm happy to post the code, but this is my first post and I'm not sure it would be helpful or just clutter things up.

Thanks for any help/suggestions you have.

Comment: Bit unclear what you doing or trying to bind to without seeing the models and view. When you display _a new Survey model_ does that contain controls that the user fills out and you need to submit that? Are you trying to submit that as well as `AddCompanyModel`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":radio").click(function() {
        var questionId = this.getAttribute("data-questionId");
        var nestedSurveyId = this.getAttribute("data-nestedSurveyId");  
        var url="/Register/jenc/company/ShowNestedSurvey/";
        var Message="";
if (nestedSurveyId != null && nestedSurveyId > 0) {
     $.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: { answerId: nestedSurveyId},
     cache: false,
     type: "POST",
    success: function (data){
       Message=data;
         },
    error: function (){
        Message="There was an error getting the survey question.";

         }
    });

questionId.html(Message);

 $("form").submit(function(event) {
        alert('submitting');
        return;
    });
}
};
```